# Syntax error Using expr substr in bash script

Tags: bash, syntax-error, substr

I have written small bash script to try to get the last x characters of a string.

```
#!/bin/bash

string="This is my string. I want THIS TEXT"
echo -e "string: $string"

length=${#string}
echo "length: $length"

start=$(($length-9))
echo "start: $start"

text=`expr substr $string $start 9`
echo "text: $text"

exit 0
```

The output is giving me a "syntax error":

```
string: This is my string. I want THIS TEXT
length: 35
start: 26
expr: syntax error
text:
```

I'm sure it's fairly simple but I can't figure it out.  Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong?  This is being run on SunOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this?

```
echo ${string:(-4)}
```

where -4 is your offset from the end